# how to get the boundingSphere for a whole scene in three.js?

Tags: three.js, bounding

How to get the bounding sphere for a whole scene in three.js?
I may try to get the bounding sphere for each object and compute the resulting union of them, but I think there may be a more straight forward method.

Comment: You just described the way to do it!

Comment: You can also compute the AABB first via `var aabb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( scene );` and then use `aabb.getBoundingSphere( sphere );`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different methods to get a boundingSphere of multiple objects dynamically. You can get first the bounding box of all of them, and then create a sphere of that bounding box... here is a sample fiddle I have shaped on [boundingSphere of a boundingBox](https://jsfiddle.net/jscastro76/qrk5Ly3b/29/).

[image]

Basically you put all the geometries into a `Group`, you get the `Box3` of the group, and then you do `getBoundingSphere` from the Box3 and position at the center. Code in the fiddle would be this.

```
let g = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(g);
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    // geometry
    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);

    // material
    var material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        opacity: 0.7,
    });

    // mesh
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(100 * Math.random(), 100 * Math.random(), 100 * Math.random());
    g.add(mesh);
}

//g.updateWorldMatrix(true);
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(400, 40, 0x0000ff, 0x808080);
gridHelper.position.y = 0;
gridHelper.position.x = 0;
scene.add(gridHelper);

let bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(g);
let helper = new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox, new THREE.Color(0, 255, 0));
scene.add(helper);

const center = new THREE.Vector3();
bbox.getCenter(center);

let bsphere = bbox.getBoundingSphere(new THREE.Sphere(center));
let m = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    opacity: 0.3,
    transparent: true
});
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(bsphere.radius, 32, 32);
let sMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, m);
scene.add(sMesh);
sMesh.position.copy(center);
```

**EDITED**: If you want to include in the boundingSphere for the scene including the lights (which could get you a huge sphere), just start from `let bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(scene)`

Comment: Glad to help! This is indeed one of the [most studied maths problems in the history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_sphere). 
The solution provided by Three js with these objects is not definitely the minimal one, but it's a good result with a great performance